# Laravel 5.2 binding session object to router

Tags: php, laravel-routing, laravel-5

Im having a trouble binding a object in session to the router. This is in a fresh install of Laravel 5.2 and this is what i have:

So my routes file:

```
    Route::resource('carts', 'CartsController');
```

In RouteServiceProvider:

```
    public function map(Router $router)
{

    $router->group(['namespace' => $this->namespace], function ($router) {
        $router->bind('carts', function ($value) {
            return Cart::get($value);
        });
        require app_path('Http/routes.php');
    });
}
```

and this is in the Cart class:

```
    public static function get($cartId)
{
    if (\Session::has('carts.' . $cartId)) {
        $cart = \Session::get('carts.' . $cartId);
    } else {
        $cart = new Cart($cartId);
    }
    return $cart;
}
```

So untill this step Session is not loaded. I tried to starting session manually by  calling `\Session::start();` but then it wouldn't get the expected data even if there are cart object in session. I also tried `dd(\Session::all())`, but it returns an empty array.

Does anyone know when to bind a object to route so that the session is also loaded?

Comment: and the middlewares are all as in default (web)

Comment: where are you adding this var to the session? and the web middleware isn't applied by default

Comment: @lagbox, what do you mean by 'this var to the session' ? `\Session` is a session facade.

Comment: You are trying to get a variable from the session. Where did you set that variable?

Comment: ah. below in another method. But it is set cuz i can see that in debugbar. @lagbox